# jQuery this and these

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this

There is a nice standard jQuery function for toggling a class on a link. Imagine a new background colour being added to the a link.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.blocklink a').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return false
        });
    });
```

Simple but I was wondering if we could save some significant time for scripts such as these considering how often something like this is needed. -- `these`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.blocklink a').click(function(){
                $(these).removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                return false
            });
        });
```

Is there a way to create the term these as a filler for whatever is the initial group of elements specified in a `.click(function    .scroll(function   .mouseenter(function` etc... etc...

Comment: I get your question. I don't think there is something like you ask but you could just do: $('.blocklink a').removeClass('active');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply: No.

But you can use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) ti simplify it a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not expecting the elements to dynamically change (i.e. you won't be adding or removing any of them), then you could cache the results of the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $these = $('.blocklink a');
    $these.click(function() {
        $these.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false
    });
});
```

Comment: I replied that it's impossible to do exactly what the original poster asked for, but I actually like your idea more than my answer :) and I recommend to do it this way instead. +1

Answer (score 1):

You won't save *significant* savings no, but you can cache the jQuery object returned by `$('.blocklink a')`;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $these = $('.blocklink a').click(function() {
        $these.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false
    });
});
```

FWIW, if you're interested in performance, the selector you have currently searches amongst *all* descendants for an `a`, but it seems from your `$(this).parent()` that you only need children.

With that in mind, you can only traverse children (rather than descendants) using the [`>` selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/);

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $these = $('.blocklink > a').click(function() {
        $these.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false
    });
});
```

Additionally, [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) searches children, where-as [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) searches all descendants.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a function?  This will prevent you from affecting anchors in other .blocklink elements

```
$('.blocklink a').click(function(){
    parentAnchors(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false
});

function parentAnchors(elem){
    return $(elem).parent().find('a');
}
```